# Only the last data in my for loop assigns

Tags: javascript

Hey I have a simple loop like this:

```
for(var i in nodes) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.className = 'box';
    d.id = 'node' + i;
    document.getElementById('node').appendChild(d);
    document.getElementById('node'+ i).innerHTML = nodes[i].name;
    document.getElementById('node'+ i).addEventListener('mousedown', function() { 
        var info = nodes[i]; display_parent(info);
    }, false);
}

function display_parent(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

The problem is all the divs hold the same information aka `the last one in the loop`, i tried to assign the data to a local variable to `info` but it still does not work.

Any ideas how I can fix that?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close the `for` loop

Comment: woops fixed! was a copy paste mistake :P

Comment: The value of `i` is not properly closed over.

Comment: You could use `nodes[this.id.substr(4)]` instead of just `nodes[i]` actually :) `</hack>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to closure in 'mousedown' event handler. You have to use something like this:

```
document.getElementById('node'+i).addEventListener('mousedown',
  (function(node) {
    return (function() {
       display_parent(node);
     });
  }(nodes[i])), false);
```